# c# Enum, Combobox, ListView Using

Tags: c#, combobox, selecteditem

I created a project that collects Personal Informations. I added a combobox to get title of Personal. Combobx items which is in ENUM, added at load. I save informations at listview, everythings Runs Perfectly i have double click event for listview. It returns all information to the their first position like Textboxes. But Combobox doesnt get its value to back. Can you show me how i can do ?

Enums Added ComboBox

```
cbUnvan.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetNames(typeof(Unvan)));
```

if Combobox item (which is Enum) selected, goes to personel.Unvan Property. (Personel is Class)

```
personel.Unvan = (Unvan)Enum.Parse(typeof(Unvan), cbUnvan.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

When i double click to listview item informations goes to their places. example is at below

```
txtTC.Text = lvTablo.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;
dtpIseGirisTarihi.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(lvTablo.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text);
```

MY PROBLEM IS HERE -- But Combobox doesnt do same action with this code below

```
cbUnvan.SelectedItem = (Unvan)Enum.Parse(typeof(Unvan), lvTablo.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[8].Text);
```

Comment: You may want to review the help center atrivles on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you, i do.